# Foreach loops and array problems

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

So after 2 hours of searching I cant seem to find what Im looking for. What I am trying to do is run a foreach loop in an array. I know its not possible but its the only way I can think of explaining what Im trying to do. The desired output is something like this:

```
groups:
  fafa:
    permissions:
      worldguard.stack: true
      worldedit.biome.list: true
      worldedit.biome.set: true
Array
(
    [groups] => Array
        (
            [fafa] => Array
                (
                    [permissions] => Array
                        (
                            [worldguard.stack] => 1
                            [worldedit.biome.list] => 1
                            [worldedit.biome.set] => 1
                        )

                )

        )

)
```

but what I seem to be getting is this:

```
groups:
  fafa:
    permissions:
      worldguard.stack: true
Array
(
    [groups] => Array
        (
            [fafa] => Array
                (
                    [permissions] => Array
                        (
                            [worldguard.stack] => 1
                        )

                )

        )

)
```

notice that the `worldedit.biome.set` and `worldedit.biome.list` dont show up. I know I am doing something wrong but I just cant figure out what the right way is to do this. Here is what I am doing:

```
<?php
include('spyc.php');
session_start();
$groupname = $_SESSION['gname'];
$permnode = $_POST['checkbox2'];
foreach($permnode as $perm){
$array = array (
    'groups'  => array(
        $groupname => array(
            'permissions' => array(
                $perm => true,

                )
            )
        )
);
}
$yaml = Spyc::YAMLDump($array);
echo '<pre>';
echo $yaml;
echo '</pre>';

echo '<pre>';
print_r($array);
echo '</pre>';

?>
```

Comment: "What I am trying to do is run a foreach loop in an array" --- array is a data structure. You cannot run anything in it.

Comment: I know but its the concept of what I am trying to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code you're overwriting the `$array` data over and over again on each loop iteration.

```
$array = array('groups' => array()); // creating empty array of groups, just once
foreach($permnode as $perm){
    if (!isset($array['groups'][$groupname])) { // if the group with a particular
                                                // name doesn't exist yet

        // then creating it and initializing with empty permissions array
        $array['groups'][$groupname] = array('permissions' => array());
    }

    // here is where you was wrong: instead of overwriting the whole array
    // with new data - you're just adding another item into permissions array
    $array['groups'][$groupname]['permissions'][$perm] = true;
}
```

Comment: IT WORKS! Thank you so much! I couldnt for the life of me think of how to do this.

Comment: @Tomas Cordero: but do you understand the difference between your and my code?

Comment: I do, I have been looking it over and figuring it out. That is usually the first thing I do when someone helps me. I go over it till i understand it